# getting special characters when reading word file from google drive

Tags: android, file, google-drive-api, uri

I am trying to store google drive word file locally to device. Below code does that, but for some (.doc) word file getting special/ascii character.

```
    InputStream inputStream = mActivity.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            inputStream));
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    String line;
    // FileInputStream fis;
    // fis = ((Activity)mActivity).openFileInput("test.txt");

    mTempFile = File.createTempFile("file", ".doc");
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(mTempFile);
    // FileOutputStream fos = ((Activity)mActivity).openFileOutput("resume.doc", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        stringBuilder.append(line);
    }
    fos.write(stringBuilder.toString().getBytes());
    fos.flush();
    fos.close();
    reader.close();
```

Some file is read properly, but some doesn't.
My intention is to download the file to device and send it to server using REST API as Multipart file.

Any help to avoid special character is highly appreciated.

Comment: `mTempFile = File.createTempFile("file", ".doc");` ??? How can that work? What is the value of `mTempFile.getAbsolutePath()` ?

Comment: value of mTempFile.getAbsolutpath is: /data/user/0/com.care.android.careview.debug/cache/filee642208189.doc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not user (Buffered)Readers.

Do not use readLine().

Dont use a StringBuilder.

They are for plain text files only. A .doc is no plain text.

Do away with them.

Just make a loop to read a chunk of bytes from the inputstream and then directly save them to the file output stream.

Comment: Thank you 'greenapps'. Your suggestion solves my issue.